# What is the preferred way to test if function was called only once?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

What is the right way to check if asynchronous function is called only once after firing event? For example:

```
userEvent.click(Button);
// What should i do here?
expect(asyncMockFunction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

The asyncMockFunction is executed inside of actual code like this:

```
doSomething(){
    const newData = await asyncMockFunction();
    this.setState({data: newData});
}
<button onClick={doSomething()}/>
```

I am thinking this might work:

```
userEvent.click(Button);
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
expect(asyncMockFunction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

But is there any simpler method that *react-testing-library* or *jest* provide? Maybe waiting for all promises to finish? Or more abstract method for waiting?

Comment: Show the code under test. How the `asyncMockFunction` be called?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`waitFor`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async#waitfor):

```
function waitFor<T>(
  callback: () => T | Promise<T>,
  options?: {
    container?: HTMLElement
    timeout?: number
    interval?: number
    onTimeout?: (error: Error) => Error
    mutationObserverOptions?: MutationObserverInit
  }
): Promise<T>
```

your example becomes:

```js
userEvent.click(Button);
// await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
await waitFor(() => expect(asyncMockFunction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1), { timeout: 2000 });
```

Comment: Documentation states about example similar to mine: `[waitFor] Wait until the callback does not throw an error. In this case, that means it'll wait until the mock function has been called once.` So, test will pass even if asyncMockFunction will be called more than once. However, I need to check if asyncMockFunction is called only once

Comment: From the same doc: `If you return a promise in the waitFor callback (either explicitly or implicitly with async syntax), then the waitFor utility will not call your callback again until that promise rejects. This allows you to waitFor things that must be checked asynchronously.`

Comment: expect().toHaveBeenCalledTimes() doesn't return promise. Besides, even if you return promise in callback, waitFor will not call callback second time if promise succesfully resolved the first time just like your quote states

Comment: `waitFor` will call the callback(not the asyncMockFunction) until the mock function has been called once, check the demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/mutable-worker-8h9r6?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.test.js&previewwindow=tests&theme=dark) (try to comment/uncomment the second `handleClick` call)

Comment: See [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-http-yzcgw?from-embed=&file=/src/App.test.js), test passes even if mockFunction was eventually called 2 times

Comment: Change `interval` to 1300 and it should work as expected

Comment: I see what you mean, but the problem is that `[waitfor] will run your callback immediately before starting the intervals.` So, if the second call of function is just slightly later, the test will pass no matter what the interval is. Try to remove first `await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 200))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234652/discussion-between-noname-and-fraction).